# Exception thrown at: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

Tags: java, json

My app builds fine, but when I run it I keep getting an exception when the following line tries to execute:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
```

I get the following exception:

exception

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException

...

Comment: What JSON library are you using? Looks like [JSON.org](www.json.org) but you wouldn't get that exception if it were.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  The apache commons lang jar has to be version 2.6.  I was using the latest version 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You need the[apache commons lang jar](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) on your classpath

Comment: I added these to my 'libraries' in netbeans: commons-lang, commons-beanutils, commons-collections, commons-logging, ezmorph.  Still does not work.